# How can I maintain redirects from a non-existing path to an existing one?

Tags: 8, redirection

With Drupal 7, the Global redirect module provided end users with a great interface to input redirects from a non-existing path to an existing one. I have installed and enabled the Redirect module for Drupal 8, but I do not see where end users can maintain a list of redirects. We are migrating an old site to Drupal 8 and we will need a method to redirect old URLs to new ones.

How can I maintain these redirects using the Redirect module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've installed and enabled the "Redirect" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect), you can manage your redirects by going to the redirect list page at `/admin/config/search/redirect`:

[image: Redirect]

You can find this route and all the other routes provided by the "Redirect" module in `redirect.routing.yml`:

```
redirect.list:
  path: '/admin/config/search/redirect'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'redirect'
    _title: 'URL redirects'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer redirects'
```

Comment: This isn't in core, you need to add it to your site to get this functionality: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect

Comment: @oknate - Ah, I forgot to add that to my response for clarity. Updated it to include that step.